# VM connections problems - fluctuating/high ping

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, openvpn

In a VM with openvpn we are having connection problems. Pinging to the ips that manage to connect, the ping varies from, for example, 100ms to 6000ms. When there are no problems the ping is normal.
This problem occurred on 04/13/2021 at approximately 15:40h (Spain time) and lasted about 15-20 minutes. This same problem also occurred on 1/4/2021 in the morning and lasted several hours.
Has anyone else had this same problem or a similar problem? Is it normal that Google does not give information about these incidents?

Answer (score 0):

You can check status of Google Cloud services with [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/).
To check your current latency to GCP regions use this tool - [link](https://gcping.com/).
From what I can see, there has been no disruptions on 13th.
I would recommend setting up monitoring or using tools like `traceroute` to locate the issue.